# Keeping HTTP session between redeploys in WildFly

Tags: java, session, wildfly

Is possible to keep HTTP session between redeploys on WildFly?

Comment: I think so, but I think you must use Database persisted sessions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might try configuring session persistence. [Here](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2014/07/save-session-state-between-redeploys.html) is a blog on how to do it.

```
<servlet-container name="default">
    <persistent-sessions path="session" relative-to="jboss.server.temp.dir"/>
    <jsp-config/>
</servlet-container>
```

However, it seems that this feature is available startinng from v8.2. I'll quote a note from this blog

> You can also achieve session passivation, when you are using a non-ha profile, by adding `<distributable/>` to your web.xml (for those using WildFly 8.1.0 or less).

Comment: Thanks so much! `<distributable/>` works like a charm for WildFly 8.1. I'll try the solution for WildFly 8.2 too.

Comment: I am going to set all my session variable class to "implements Serializable"

Comment: Seems distributable attribute must be in web.xml in order for persistent-sessions to work.  Using Wildfly 16 and Keycloak 5 with Elytron.   Thought distributable only applied to domain/cluster setups, but apparently it applies to standalone setup too.  Note: session persistence on single server mode (non clustered) worked in GlassFish without distributable...

Answer (score 2):

`<distributable/>` in **web.xml** deployed to *standalone* may lead you to [WFLY-3715](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243458) (logs polluted with undertow exceptions).

Alternative option can be to  configure persistent sessions [in standalone.xml](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2014/07/save-session-state-between-redeploys.html) or with **jboss-cli.sh**. JBoss CLI command worth to mention, as it can be used within maven plugin for WildFly.

```
/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default/setting=persistent-sessions:add(path="session", relative-to="jboss.server.temp.dir")
```

Log pollution example:

```
2016-12-29 09:39:48,464 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-26) UT005023: Exception handling request to /resources/js/holder.js: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 15 seconds for key SessionCreationMetaDataKey(EkmgBEYcvqFxNF_T2dDwEfyXkh7Nzcv2nTKBYy9G) and requestor GlobalTransaction::13:local. Lock is held by GlobalTransaction::12:local
        at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.lock(DefaultLockManager.java:238)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lockAndRecord(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:193)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.checkPendingAndLockKey(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:193)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockOrRegisterBackupLock(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.PessimisticLockingInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(PessimisticLockingInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:43)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistReadAndInvokeNext(TxInterceptor.java:346)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(TxInterceptor.java:331)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:43)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:114)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:85)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:43)
........
```